# Why does SQL Server Management Studio get these syntax errors from copied code

Tags: sql-server, ssms

So while testing some code, I discovered odd behavior with code I had pasted in a query window. Below is a simplified example of where I got the code from:

```
declare @a nvarchar(max) = '';

select @a = 'select ' + cast(n as char(1)) + ';' + char(13) + 'GO' + char(13) from nums where n = 1;

print @a

exec sp_executesql @a
```

This was executed in a query window in SSMS. It errors, of course, because of that `GO` delimiter that won't work in dynamic SQL.

However, just so I could confirm the code itself was OK, I copied it into a new query window. To continue the example:

```
select 1;
GO

select 1
GO
```

The first statement gives a syntax error, and the second treats the `GO` as a column alias. Interestingly, this continued to be true if I just typed code directly into that query window. It didn't affect other windows or new ones, just the one I had pasted the `PRINT` results into.

The last interesting fact about this is that if I compared doing a `LEN()` on the above example in the "bad" query window versus one that works as expected, the "bad" query is 26 characters long, but the normal one is 31.

I found that backspacing all the characters didn't seem to help, but that if I did a Select All and did a delete that this seemed to fix it. I assume this means it's getting a non-printable character, but if I do a Select All and copy into Notepad++ with a Show All Symbols option, I don't see anything of note.

Does anyone know why SSMS is behaving this way? I'm using version 17.9 (and running against a SQL Server 2014 instance if that matters).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`char(13)` is Carriage Return (CR).
`char(10)` is Linefeed (LF).

Windows uses CRLF as a line terminator.
Linux uses LF as a line terminator.

No modern environment uses just CR as a line terminator as your script does.  SSMS happens to render CR by inserting vertical space, and this behavior probably is inherited from the underlying Visual Studio codebase.

SSMS's TSQL batch parser, however, doesn't recognize CR as a line terminator, so it doesn't look for the GO symbol following CR.  It works with LF or CRLF.

Comment: Is there a reason that new code typed in that window also behaves oddly (until you Ctrl+A, delete at least)? Is it continuing to add those vertical spaces?

Comment: The Visual Studio behavior appears to be that when you break a line, it inserts whatever line terminator it finds on the end of that line.  And your script as a CR after `GO`.  So if you remove the line break before GO and break the line again, it puts CR back.